# Is there an idiom for "winning a contest because you were the only participant"?

Tags: idiom-requests

Is there an idiom for winning a contest because you are the only participant and there is no competitor?

Comment: Apparently, it depends on which side of the pond you're on (?).

Comment: This expression might be useful to you: "In the land of the blind, the one-eyed jack is king."

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/253485/word-for-winning-because-the-competitors-were-miraculously-all-worse

Answer (score 106, accepted):

**Winner by default**. This is a common expression in America for one-on-one sports like wrestling and tennis, especially when part of a larger tournament.

*Suzanne won her match by default when the Deerfield High School bus broke down, leaving her opponent miles away from the meet.*

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59414/discussion-on-answer-by-stu-w-is-there-an-idiom-for-winning-a-contest-because-y).

Comment: https://youtu.be/RhvIISDoarU

Answer (score 63):

This is known as a **walkover**.

It comes from horse racing where the sole contesting horse had still to *walk over* the course to win. The following is from [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/walkover):

> Definition of **walkover**
>
> 1:  a one-sided contest :  an easy or uncontested victory
>
> 2:  a horse race with only one starter

The earliest citations in the OED (1928) (there spelled “walk-over”) are of metaphoric use in an article in the ‘Times’ concerning a parliamentary election in 1838 (spelled “walk over”), and one relating to a horserace in 1861 (hyphenated spelling), although it is not entirely clear whether the latter use is literal or metaphoric. A clear example of literal use in relation to horse racing is in the [Report of the California State Agricultural Society of 1885](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=rUAPAQAAIAAJ&q=%22walkover%22&dq=%22walkover%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj53bOGipbUAhVnD8AKHVDSAUEQ6AEIOzAF):

> On Monday, the fifteenth, the track was in the best possible condition when the first race was called, which was the Maturity stake for four-year olds, a dash of three miles. For this William Boots’ colt Padre had a *walkover*—Lucky B, Gano, and Augusta E paying forfeit.

However [race records from the 18th Century](http://www.bloodlines.net/TB/Bios/Eclipse.htm) include the verbal use, “walked over”, e.g.

> Eclipse ch c 1764 (Shakespeare or Marske - Spiletta, by Regulus)…
>
> In 1769 he won a £50 Plate at Epsom…
>
> *Walked over* for the King’s Plate at the same meeting.…

As regards contemporary use, in addition to [horse racing](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/sport/horseracing/8451803/Leicester-must-stage-walkover-as-tariff-row-escalates-leading-to-one-horse-race.html), the term is employed in other sports, including [tennis](https://www.theguardian.com/sport/2016/nov/05/andy-murray-becomes-tennis-world-no1-milos-raonic-walkover-paris), [athletics](http://loughboroughsport.com/athletic-union/files/2013/09/BUCS-League-Teams-Walkover-Policy.pdf), and [basketball](http://websites.sportstg.com/assoc_page.cgi?c=0-4310-0-0-0&sID=51163&&news_task=DETAIL&articleID=4702723) and [badminton](http://www.thestar.com.my/sport/badminton/2017/04/02/changoh-concede-walkover-in-indian-open-semifinals/).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59415/discussion-on-answer-by-david-is-there-an-idiom-for-winning-a-contest-because-y).

Comment: >A **walkover**, or **W.O**. (originally two words: "walk over"), is the awarding of a victory to a contestant because there are no other contestants or the other contestants have been disqualified or have forfeited. The term can apply in sport but also to elections, when it is also referred to as winning "by default" [...] The word originates from horseracing in the United Kingdom, where an entrant in a one-horse race run under Jockey Club rules has at least to "walk over" the course before being awarded victory. –[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walkover)

Comment: @Mazura — Thanks. Have added the 18th Century example from one of the web pages cited in the Wikipedia article. Unfortunately it is not fully referenced. (Nor are most of the assertions in Wikipedia.)

Answer (score 45):

I was trying to remember the phrase that I've heard most often (I knew it was "Winner of a... race.") when I saw the comment by Chris Chudziki under David's answer, which filled in the rest of the phrase:

> Winner of a one-horse race.

Upon searching for that exact phrase, it seems that it is most often used as part of an insult:

"He couldn't pick the winner of a one-horse race."

But it *is* used in the manner you described, and I think most native English speakers (at least on the U.S. side of the pond) would recognize the phrase.

Comment: +1. I think it's also worth mentioning that "one-horse race" is also used metaphorically to mean an easy win, not just when there is literally only one candidate. (In fact, this might be the more common use? I'm not sure.)

Comment: @ChrisChudzicki Quite possibly. I've always assumed (when I've heard the insult) that there was literally only one horse in the race, and there are races where all but one of the horses are scratched from the race, but you may be right.

Comment: "One horse race" is almost always used to mean that the outcome was a foregone conclusion, virtually never that there was literally only one runner.

Comment: I've seen it used literally in a political context—when a candidate (frequently the incumbent) is running uncontested, that's a *one horse race*. (Horse races seem to be the go-to metaphor for elections in the US.)

Comment: Its a nice turn of phrase, and I thank you for introducing me to it. However, I'd say the fact I wasn't familiar with it, and even you weren't without having to do an internet search, points to this likely not being a very common "idiom".

Comment: @OP, in "He couldn't pick the winner of a one-horse race." The offense is about "He" and not about the winner. It is saying that "He" is terrible about making choices, because even when there is one option, he will pick the wrong one.

Comment: @Mandrill Not sure if I'm the OP you are referring to or if Dante deleted a comment, but I'm aware of who the subject of the joke is, I only include the phrase because it's the most common usage.

Comment: @T.E.D. : I'm disagreeing, suggesting this was a lack of familiarity, but not necessarily because of notable obscurity of the phrase.

Answer (score 24):

"Win by default" would sum up winning a competition when there is no opponent.

Comment: That answer has already been given.

Comment: Looks like Kelly H. was before Stu W on this by a few minutes?  Regardless, is this even an idiom as requested by Dante?

Comment: @Chenmunka  the OP posted the answer three minutes earlier than Stu W. a pity Kelly didn't provide a dictionary link, that would have made a sizeable difference.

Comment: @thomj1332 - Sure its an idiom. The *literal* meaning is that the opponent(s) defaulted. Using it for a situation where there was never any opponent in the first place is idiomatic.

Answer (score 9):

From the Free Dictionary comes this entry for [No Contest](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/contest):

> 1. Lit. [in games] a situation where one team fails to appear for a competition.
>      *It was declared no contest because the opposing team was stuck in traffic out on the expressway.*
> 2. Fig. a situation where the winner-to-be of a contest is obvious even before holding the contest.
>      *It was no contest. The wrestler was so big and strong that no one could have defeated him.*

Answer (score 5):

In the specific circumstance that the contest is an election, in Canadian English you could say that the contestant is **acclaimed**.

From the OED, **acclamation**:

> *Canad.* (An instance of) election to an assembly by unanimous or overwhelming assent, unopposed

The Canadian parliament [notes that](https://lop.parl.ca/ParlInfo/Compilations/HouseOfCommons/ElectedByAcclamation.aspx)

> In Canada, a Member is said to be elected or returned by acclamation when no other candidate has come forward at an election and no vote is held.

Perhaps not surprisingly, most of the google hits for this sense of the term come from Canadian universities' student elections (see the numerous candidates marked "acclaimed" in the [University of Waterloo's recent election](http://www.feds.ca/home/upcoming-feds-election-candidates-announced/)), since it's relatively rare for actual political positions to go uncontested.

I was surprised no one had posted this, even if it isn't truly generalizable to all contests, because I had no notion that it was exclusively a Canadianism before today; I use the term relatively frequently and am confident that others around me understand it.

Comment: I didn't realize this was a Canadianism, either.  I was going to post but you beat me to it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

In a tournament, if it results specifically from mathematical quirks, like there being an odd number of participants, it may be called a "[bye](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bye)", although I'm uncertain whether that may refer to the victory itself, or just the actual (un-played) game:

> the position of a participant in a tournament who advances to the next round without playing

Comment: No. A bye is for a single round only, where there is at least one more round, which indicates more opponents. The OP is asking about being the only contestant, in which case a bye would  not apply.

Answer (score 3):

## [*a one-horse show*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+one-horse+race)

This suggests that there was one and only one competitor.

In the case of a *one-horse race* the common interpretation is that, although there were other competitors, one particular individual was a clear and almost uncontested winner.

Comment: I think it's supposed to be a one-horse *show*, not race. I googled your answer and the results suggest that. https://www.google.com.ph/search?q=one+horse+show&rlz=1C1NHXL_enPH727PH727&oq=one+horse+show&aqs=chrome..69i57.2063j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 3):

Australia has the idiom 'lay-down misere', which comes from gambling: you could lay all your cards down and still win. As a comment mentions, 'pulling a Bradbury', after our gold medal winning speed skater who was the only person to avoid a collision in his Olympic races, is also an idiom, but won't travel.

If neither of these more colourful phrases suit, 'walkover' is a good idiom that will travel, and 'winner by default' isn't exactly idiomatic but describes what's going on clearly.

Comment: Short track speed skater, to be precise.